# Constructing REST API endpoints for WSO2 Identity Server login

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

What are the **HTTP requests needed to login to WSO2 Identity Server** using **code** grant to get an **OIDC token**

Answer (score 0):

There are no out of the box REST API for login as of now. However have a look at this sample done by [Prabath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804637/prabath-siriwardena) which provides a lightweight REST API for login[2]

[2] https://github.com/facilelogin/aratuwa/tree/master/carbon-security/org.wso2.carbon.security.login

Comment: cool! but I need to know how the request(s) is/are constructed no.3 of [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Session+Management+with+Playground).

Comment: so do you want to login to IS using OpenID connect?

Comment: well you can userhttps://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Resource+Owner+Password+Credentials+Grant and get an OIDC toke. But that is discouraged as credentials are sent with the token request.

Comment: security. because i will invoke the login endpoint via client-side javascript

Comment: hmm in that case you can go for the implicit flow.  basically need to construct a GET request like this https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=JqB4NGZLMC6L3n4jz094FMls2Joa&redirect_uri=https://localhost/callback&scope=openid&nonce=1233

Comment: [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614302/http-requests-for-wso2-identity-server-user-authentication) a better version of my question